# UITableView not reloading data after request

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, uitableview, reloaddata

I am currently developping an app with Swift. Here is the sum up : 
I have a Menu which appear on the left side when clicking on a top bar button and disappear by clicking again. Below this menu, I have multiple ContainerViews which change according to the click on the Menu, all the containerViews are hidden except the one wanted. So far, no problems. 
However, a container has an embed segue to a TableViewController which shows data from my server in json. 
Therefore, and this might be the problem, when I click on the menu to show this container, I would like to fetch my data and to display it on the TableView. However, the method cellForRowAtIndexPath is never called whereas numberOfRowsInSection is called (and return more than 0).

I know that my tableViewController is loaded when the application launches even if it is a container in the initial ViewController.

Here is my code when the user clicks on the menu :

```
indexQuestionsContainer.alpha=1;
var questionsIndexViewController : QuestionsListTableViewController = QuestionsListTableViewController();
for controller in self.childViewControllers
{
    if (controller.title=="indexQuestions")
    {
        questionsIndexViewController = controller as! QuestionsListTableViewController
    }
}
questionsIndexViewController.getQuestions();
```

And here is my code for getQuestions() :

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil
        {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding);
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
            do{
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments) as! NSArray
                for item in json
                {
                    let item = item as! [String:AnyObject];
                    let id:Int? = Int(item["id"] as! String);
                    let text = item["text"] as! String;
                    var q = Question();
                    q.idAuthor=id!;
                    q.text=text;
                    self.questions.append(q);
                }
            }catch {
                print("Error with Json: \(error)")
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                })
            })
        }

    }
    task.resume()
```

The numberOfRowsInSection returns self.questions.count which is > 0 (proof with debug) and numberOfSections returns 1..

And my tableView does not reload...

Some help would be really appreciated, thanks in advance !

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` only gets called when a cell needs to be displayed - if `numberOfRowsInSection` returns 1000, `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will only be called for those that fit on the screen. Therefore, it sounds like none of your cells need to be displayed. Is the treeView visible? Maybe give it a border so you can see where it appears.

Comment: When the view is loaded (beginning of the app), I have put a test which returns 1 cell and this cell is correctly displayed, however I want to change this cell and add others when I "un-hide" the view (by clicking on the menu) by fetching data of my server.. And at this point, nothing is reloaded. And yes, the treeView is visible

Comment: Ok, problem solved ! I was browsing my childViewControllers and test the one I wanted with its identifier (which I did not specify in the storyboard).. Therefore, it executed my methods over a new TableViewController not displayed.. Thanks